# How do I save files to the desktop?

Tags: release-loki

I know you could save files to the Desktop in Kali Linux. But it has been a while, so I have no idea where the "Desktop" is located in the elementary OS filesystem. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Desktop folder in your home folder, but nothing in there will show up on the desktop. elementary OS doesn't show icons on a desktop.

Comment: Pfffft! Strange, I don't see the desktop folder :/

Comment: You can make one. Just make sure the d in Desktop is capitalized. Put it in the same folder with your Downloads and Pictures folders and any app looking to download something to the Desktop will download it there

Comment: This is not accurate; elementary OS does not ship with a Desktop folder.

Comment: Yes, elementaryOS do not support Desktop folder. You can create one as most of us do like you create any regular folder, but you will not see the files from the Desktop folder into your computer desktop - elementary OS do not support such a feature.